# Angular 8 AutoFocus directive

Tags: angular, directive

I am creating an autofocus directive for an input of my template like this :

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutofocus]',
})
export class AutofocusDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

And I have two problems :
First, my autofocus directive spec file returns me an error :

```
   import { AutofocusDirective } from './autofocus.directive';

describe('AutofocusDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new AutofocusDirective(); //Expected 1 argument and I don't know which
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And the second error is on the console, after injecting my autodirective in the constructor of my component, and place the "autofocus" directive like this :

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="2-ddf"
                        formControlName="dtFin"appAutofocus #dtFin>
```

My console returns me this message :
core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TabPensionInvaliditeComponent -> AutofocusDirective]:

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem:

When instantiating a `class`, as you did, you must pass all non-optional parameters. To test a `directive` properly, I'd recommend you to take a look at [Attribute Directive Testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#attribute-directive-testing).

For the second problem:

You probably forgot to add `AutofocusDirective` in the `@NgModule#declarations`.

<kbd>[**Working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6wuoz)</kbd>